# Get column DataType from SSAS tabular DB using ADOMD

Tags: c#, ssas, adomd.net, ssas-2012, ssas-tabular

How can I get DataType information of each and every column of a SSAS tabular cube? I know how to [execute a query and then get the SchemaInformation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123475(v=sql.110).aspx) (which also provides columns DataType).

I want to read any given cube, get the list of dimensions & for each dimesnion, I should be able to read the attributes & for each attribute, I want to read the Attribute's (column's) DataType.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ADOMD, but perhaps you could query the [SSAS DMVs](https://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2011/03/01/ssas-dmv-queries-cube-metadata/). As an example, check out the [MDSCHEMA_MEASURES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms126250.aspx) .  It will tell you the data type, numeric precision, and numeric scale of each measure.

Comment: @mmarie: Thank you for the reply. We have tried using DMV and XMLA queries but these queries are not considering view or prespective on top of a cube. I want to extract data from prespective but these queries are not  taking into consideration those view\prespective.

Comment: @mmarie: The XMLA queries have something called RestrictionList but even that is not working as expected`<Restrictions>
                <RestrictionList>
                        <CATALOG_NAME>test</CATALOG_NAME>
                        <PERSPECTIVE_NAME>View</PERSPECTIVE_NAME>
                </RestrictionList>`